# Is corrected astigmatism disqualifying for an EASA Class 1 medical?

Tags: medical, easa-regulations

I realize there are similar questions on the site already, but not one specifically dealt with my problem. I reside and plan to work in Europe so I looked up the EASA regulations, but I couldn't really make sense of them. My question is: I have astigmatism, which is corrected by my glasses. I am also shortsighted, which is also corrected. Does this disqualify me for a Class 1 license?

Answer (score 2):

I have a registered astigmatism on one eye that is balanced by the other eye. I have a Class 1 medical w.o. problems. In my medical record, the Doc wrote that my astigmatism corresponds to a .75 dpt on one eye.

He also told me that absolute values are not important, important is that the astigmatism is corrected by either the other eye, some glasses or it is so low that the brain can even correct for it.